# Trying to run the git clone command on a Windows computer, pulling from an AWS Remote Server

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have an AWS Linux Ubuntu instance that I am using to host a couple of git remote repositories. The remote repository supports git-annex. I am able to push/pull/clone/etc. between my mac and my AWS instance.

The problem I am having is with my Windows (OS: Windows 7) computer. I downloaded msysgit and installed it, along with git-annex. When I tried to run

> git clone ubuntu@SERVER.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/git-repo/test.git

(with the correct value filled in for SERVER) I got the following error:

> Cloning into 'test' ...
>
> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Btw, I am able to ssh in via the following command

> ssh -i ~/Desktop/gitserverkey.pem ubuntu@SERVER.amazonaws.com

When I accessed the instance with another (and my mac) mac, I was able to do so with just the AWS keypair gitserverkey.pem. The steps I used for my macs are as follows:

> ~ cd Desktop/localgitrepo
>
> ~ chmod 0400 ~/Downloads/gitserverkey.pem
>
> ~ ssh-add ~/Downloads/gitserverkey.pem
>
> ~ git clone ubuntu@SERVER.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/git-repo/test.git

I say this because some stackoverflow pages (and the Google) have recommended copying my windows's computer's private key into the known_hosts file of my AWS instance. I don't think this should be necessary, since I did not have to for my mac and because I am able to ssh in.

My question is, what are the equivalent steps for Windows as those I executed for my mac? How do I clone my server repository onto my local windows computer? A tutorial or some insight into my error would be really helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up solving my problem was creating and modifying ~/.ssh/config and adding the following lines of code:

```
⁃   Host amazonaws.com
⁃   User ubuntu
⁃   Hostname SERVER.amazonaws
⁃   PreferredAuthentications public key
⁃   Port 22
⁃   IdentityFile ~/Desktop/serverkey.pem
```

ssh worked, but git clone didn't because git clone didn't know where to find the necessary key.

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `ssh-add` on your Mac, you were adding the `gitserverkey.pem` key to that machine's ssh-agent, which can then provide it for Git to use for the session.

You need to do the same on your Windows machine - inside the msysgit shell, run the ssh-add command to add the proper key to the agent before you try to clone.